# pygtk cellrenderertoggle editable

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have the following code in pygtk:

```
....
    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.columns["hour"] = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Uur", rendererText, text=0)
    self.columns["hour"].set_sort_column_id(0)   
    self.treeview.append_column(self.columns["hour"])

    self.columnControls["ond"] = gtk.CellRendererToggle()
    self.columns["ond"] = gtk.TreeViewColumn("ond", self.columnControls["ond"], active=1)
    self.columns["ond"].set_sort_column_id(1)   
    self.treeview.append_column(self.columns["ond"])
....
```

So, I'd personally expect that if I click the checkbox that appears in the column entrys would be "togglable", but it isn't. Is this because of my OS (Mac OS X 10.8), or is there some kind of property I forgot to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind a callback function, which may reverse the value in that GtkListStore/GtkTreeStore, to `toggled` signal. Like this:

```
 def on_cellrenderertoggle_toggled(self, cellrenderertoggle, path):
    # self.liststore is the tree modal of that treeview
    self.liststore[path][1] = not self.liststore[path][1]
```

A full tutorial can be found here: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrenderertoggle